# Angle grinder brand (Not working)

Tags: grinder, angle-grinder

How can I find out this angle grinder model/brand? The label has come off so I dont know the model. The grinder is not working and I believe it is the brushes, how can I know what brushes to buy if I dont know the brand or the model? I was able to read something I believe it is "Pa6 ge30"

[img]https://image.ibb.co/jamo5a/17373171_1500457109989280_506947401_o.jpg
[img]https://image.ibb.co/fyrSyv/17351223_1500456736655984_406501642_n.jpg
[img]https://image.ibb.co/ktT1Qa/17430704_1500456806655977_787717601_o.jpg
[img]https://image.ibb.co/iNQ4dv/17392696_1500456909989300_2107525600_n.jpg
[img]https://image.ibb.co/bRWMQa/17410313_1500456943322630_1658083182_n.jpg
[img]https://image.ibb.co/gUzVJv/17408258_1500457016655956_1132823352_o.jpg
[img]https://image.ibb.co/ms6XWF/17408100_1500457046655953_1457825632_o.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few thoughts...

I don't recognize it, so can't be directly helpful.

Pa6 is usually just a reference to the plastic; not sure about the ge30 part.

You might get lucky by pulling the existing brush/holder and going to a good repair place to see if they have something you can work with.

Have you checked the switch? Failure there would make this a write-off, even with a positive identification.

I'm not a fan of throwing stuff away, but realistically, grinders are a dime a dozen. You can get a name brand used one for about triple what a set of brushes would cost you. You can get a bargain bin (ie, will only work for a little while) one for about the same as a set of brushes.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to check the switch and try going to a repair shop. Yeah I didn't want to throw it away cause I am on a tight budget